# Flutter Navigation based on auth state

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-provider

I'm building a Flutter app with user authentification (firebase but whatever) and would like to have two sets of routes for authenticated and unauthenticated users:

- unauthenticated users:
  /login
  /register
  ...
- authenticated users:
  /home
  ...

I tried to have on the top widget a switch with something like that:

```
 switch(_user.status) {
        case UserStatus.Unauthenticated:
       return MaterialApp(
                      title: _title,
                        theme: _themeData,
                        routes: ....
                        initialRoute: "/login",
                      );
        case UserStatus.Authenticated:
       return MaterialApp(
                      title: _title,
                        theme: _themeData,
                        onGenerateRoute: _generateRoute,
                        initialRoute: "/",
                      );
```

(I got the `_user` value with a `ChangeNotifierProvider` at the top of the tree) but apparently it's not possible to have 2 top navigators.

Second, I tried to push the switch in the `_generateRoute` function but there is some caching: when the tree is rebuilt (for example when `_user.status` change) the `_generateRoute` function is not called again and so that doesn't work.

How do you solve this?

Comment: I have same issue, hurry help pls :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator for this:

```
MaterialApp(
  title: _title,
  theme: _themeData,
  routes: ....
  initialRoute: _user.status == UserStatus.Unauthenticated ? "/login" : "",
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work :
When the user is authentified, the Application widget is rebuild but not the MaterialApp widget and the LoginPage still appears... :-(